# PHP Show menus/submenus according to the value of a variable

Tags: php

I have a navigation bar in which I am trying to show menus/buttons, according to the type of user. I get the type of user via a variable called $isManager. 
The good news is that it works on every browser, except firefox.
Code looks like this:

```
<?php
    if ($isManager === '2'){
?>
        <li><a href="view.php">View</a></li>
<?php
   }
?>
```

Can you suggest an alternative to this, or is Firefox somehow ignoring or not accepting the true condition here ?

Comment: PHP is a server side language, so it has nothing to do with Firefox whatsoever.

Comment: You need to share your HTML, CSS, JS codes.

Comment: Agree with you here. The condition is true however and I know this because I've been echoing the value of $isManager in other browsers and it is good, and looks ok in everything except firefox for some reason...

Comment: Are you ensure `$isManager` data type is string?? if not, please reply the result of `var_dump($isManager)`.

Comment: The result is: string(1) "1"

Answer (score 0):

When you use `===`, it is for strict checking. So make sure that your`$isManager` is string type. If it is integer then try

```
<?php
    if ($isManager === 2){
?>
        <li><a href="view.php">View</a></li>
<?php
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are Using `===` it means you want to check by its typeof too.

and after that you wrote '2', so it will missmatch the results and not going to the condition, instead try the following.

`<?php`
    `if ($isManager === 2){`
`?>`
        `<li><a href="view.php">View</a></li>`
`<?php`
`}`
`?>`